# DateTimePickComponent date pick doesen't full show

Tags: reactjs, react-native, syncfusion

I'm using DateTimePickComponent from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-calendars" but in every page where I use the component I get the window for pick the date not fulling show, it's like sliced in half.

```
<DateTimePickerComponent
        format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"
        id="StartTime"
        data-name="StartTime"
        name="StartTime"
        value={new Date(props.startTime || props.StartTime)}
      ></DateTimePickerComponent>
```

[image]

Comment: on what platform?

Comment: react js @Krismu

Comment: @VondeTaconadis Could you share your code in codesandbox?

Comment: @MajidM. if I try to setup the datetimepickercomponent on sandbox I only get a input text without the plugin

Comment: @VondeTaconadis,

The issue might be due to any local styles overriding the DateTimePickComponent’s styles. If you have done any customization, ensure this by removing them. The component renders as expected in the sample below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xyabna

If you still face the issue, try to replicate it in the above sample. It will be helpful to validate and provide a solution.